# Can I Migrate To a Different Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've inherited a web app has Facebook oAuth integration with Facebook. It uses Facebook for login as well as making API calls to graph for other purposes.

The original developers set up multiple apps per environment instead of making one parent app and using child testing apps. However, I cannot fund the production app. That is, I have the app ID and the secret, but can't find the actual app. I made some API calls to get the user ID of the person who set it up but he does not respond to my requests.

What are my options? Can I somehow migrate production to a new app? The facebook IDs the app use are app-scoped, so what I'd like to do is make the production app the one app both development/staging etc. use.

Besides for needing control over the production app, if I switch to use a different app for production, each users' facebook ID will be different and thus each existing user will be seen as a new, distinct user even if the user has already registered.

Comment: App-scoped user IDs can be “translated” between different apps - but for that, the apps need to be added to the same business to begin with, and if you have no admin access to the old app, that can’t be done. I don’t think there is _any_ way here to keep your old user logins working, if you don’t have access to the old app. (If you want to keep it uid based; if you have user email addresses recorded in your database, then you could try and identify them via that. But not every FB user has an email set to begin with …)

Comment: _“so what I'd like to do is make the production app the one app both development/staging etc. use.”_ - you can not have one app in live and dev mode at the same time. You should create a _test app_ of your live app for development purposes. Test apps see the same app-scoped user ids as their “original” that you created them from does.